# How To Achieve Boxed Matrix entries

Tags: formatting, matrices, highlighting, vector

I am wanting to see how one can achieve the following in LaTeX:

[image]

`\tilde A`, `\hat A`, `\tilde B`, `\hat B`, `\tilde C^{-1}`, `\hat C^{-1}` and `D` are all matrices. `$\Lambda$` is the new matrix formed from the boxed terms.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

One solution is use of the `tikzmark` library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,            % new
                tikzmark}       % new
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-2]
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
~\tikzmarknode{a}{\hat{A}}     
            &   \hat{B}     &   \hat{C}^{-1}    &   D   \\ 
~\tilde{A}  &   \tilde{B}   &   \tikzmarknode{b}{\tilde{C}^{-1}}  
                                                &   D   \\
\end{pmatrix}
\]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node [draw=red, semithick, inner sep=2pt, rounded corners, 
       fit=(a) (b), label=below:{$=\Lambda^T$}] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\vspace{2ex}
\lipsum[1][3-4]
\end{document}
```

which after two compilation gives:

[image]

**Edit:**
Another possibilities is drawn your matrix as Ti*k*Z matrix. IN this case you not reserve vertical space for node's label as is done with `\vspace{2ex}` in the first example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,
                matrix}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
             left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)
             ]
{
\hat{A}     &   \hat{B}     &   \hat{C}^{-1}    &   D   \\
~\tilde{A}  &   \tilde{B}   &   \tilde{C}^{-1}  &   D   \\
};
\node [draw=red, semithick, inner sep=2pt, rounded corners,
       fit=(m-1-1) (m-2-3), label=below:{$=\Lambda^T$}] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

which after one compilation gives:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution that doesn't require loading any packages.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
  \left(\begin{array}{@{} |ccc|c @{}}
      \cline{1-3}
      \hat{A} & \hat{B} & \hat{C}^{-1^{\mathstrut}} & D \\
      \tilde{A} & \tilde{B} & \tilde{C}^{-1} & D \\
      \cline{1-3}
  \end{array}\right) \\
  \Lambda^{T}~ 
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Watch out those lower left and lower right corners.

Comment: @mickep - That issue vanishes automatically if the `array` is loaded — which will generally be the case in real-world documents.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option with `nicematrix`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[last-row, left-margin=.5em]
  \Block[draw, rounded-corners]{2-3}{}\hat{A} & \hat{B} & \hat{C}^{-1} & D\rule{0pt}{3ex}\\[1ex]
  \tilde{A} & \tilde{B} & \tilde{C}^{-1} & D\\
  \Block{1-3}{\Lambda^{T}{\rule{0pt}{3ex}}}
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

You can change the color of the box if you wish by setting
`\Block[draw=red, rounded-corners]`